# What do I store in the password field in my DB when a user logs in with Google or Facebook?

Tags: facebook, oauth, oauth-2.0

In my app there are 4 options:

• Login with facebook

• Login with Google

• Login with LinkedIn

• Sign up manually

When a user logs in via facebook for example, I can retrieve their email, mobile number, gender etc etc. Now when I go to store this information in my database what should I put in the password field of that account?

I am using oAuth2 + hashing and salting all my passwords and this has really stumped me.

Any help or pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't store any password for such users. Users without password will be able to log in just by the third-party authentication services. I think that's the point of using the services - not to store passwords in every web application.

If you want to have the DB password field mandatory, move it to an associated one-to-one table that will hold it. For example if your current table is called Users, you can create a new table Accounts.